# Reducer not updating state on action being fired and hence redux store/state not being updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Actions fired from mediaSagas.js not entering the reducer function and hence reducer store/state not being updated.
I have tried debugging but not able to find the root cause.

actionTypes.js

```
export const FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS = 'FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS';
export const SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS = 'SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS';
```

imageReducer.js

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';

export default function (state = initialState.images, action) {
  console.log("action",action); // I am not getting action with type FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS or SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return [...state, action.images];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

videoReducer.js

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';

export default function (state = initialState.videos, action) {
  console.log("action",action); // I am not getting action with type FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS or SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS:
      return [...state, action.videos];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

initialState.js

```
export default {
  images: [],
  videos: []
};
```

mediaSagas.js

```
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { unsplashImages, shutterStockVideos } from '../Api/api';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';


export default function* searchMediaSaga({ payload }) {
  console.log("saga entered");
  try {
    const videos = yield call(shutterStockVideos, payload);
    const images = yield call(unsplashImages, payload);
    console.log("vids",videos); // I am getting the videos data here
    console.log("img",images); // I am getting the image data here
    yield [
      put({ type: types.SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS, videos }),
      put({ type: types.FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS,images}),
    ];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("err",error);
    yield put({ type: 'SEARCH_MEDIA_FAILURE', error });
  }
}
```

watchers.js

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import  searchMediaSaga  from './mediaSagas';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';

// Watches for SEARCH_MEDIA_REQUEST action type asynchronously
export default function* watchSearchMedia() {
  yield takeLatest(types.SEARCH_MEDIA_REQUEST, searchMediaSaga);
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import images from './imageReducer';
import videos from './videoReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  images, 
  videos
});

export default rootReducer;
```

sagas/index.js

```
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import watchSearchMedia from './watchers';

export default function* startForman() {
  yield fork(watchSearchMedia);
}
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import rootSaga from '../sagas'; // TODO: Next step

const configureStore = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(); 
  return {
    ...createStore(rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
    runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  };
};

export default configureStore;
```

src/index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './containers/App'
import MediaGalleryPage from './containers/MediaGalleryPage'

const store = configureStore();
store.subscribe(() => {
  const newState = store.getState();
  // check out your updated state
  console.log("NewState", newState) // always giving empty image and video arrays
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>  
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/library" component={MediaGalleryPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Is the saga being invoked?

Comment: @elvis_ferns : Yes saga is being invoked and am getting data from API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue , In mediaSagas.js I was using the put effect in parallel but the way I am using is deprecated now . Check all([...effects]) - parallel effects in redux saga docs which resolved my issue .

Deprecated way as I have used above -

```
yield [
      put({ type: types.SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS, videos }),
      put({ type: types.FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS,images}),
    ];
```

New way(Correct way) which resolved my issue

```
yield all([
      put({ type: types.SHUTTER_VIDEOS_SUCCESS, videos }),
      put({ type: types.FLICKR_IMAGES_SUCCESS,images })
    ]);
```

Github link which pointed me to the solution -
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/459

Comment: What is the use of using put effect parallely??

Comment: @elvis_ferns:  Definition of **all** effect as per docs - Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to run multiple Effects in parallel and wait for all of them to complete. It's quite the corresponding API to standard Promise#all. Rather than writing **put** effect individually and waiting for each one of them , I used put parallely as anyhow I need to wait till both of them complete

Comment: parallel does not mean concurrent. state will trigger in different ticks

Comment: I am not sure  how state will update but the reason I used **put effect** parallely/yieldall is because my multiple **put** dont depend on one another to complete , they can be trigerred all at once . If there would have been dependency , I would have used yield put individually